# How is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ the same as $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm a bit confused about permutations in my stats course:

How is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ the same as $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)$

I'm use to learning it permutations being $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ but not the other way. Any explanations?

Comment: Probably, it is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$

Comment: Did you write it out for some small numbers? Also, do be careful with parentheses. If you mean $(n - r)!$ this is easy to see by writing out the definition, and if you mean $n - r!$ this is something else entirely.

Comment: It should be $\left(n-r\right)!$.

Comment: sorry lemme edit

Answer (score 3):

Cancelling the numerator and denominator gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}
&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)\color{#C00000}{(n-r)(n-r-1)\cdots1}}{\color{#C00000}{(n-r)(n-r-1)\cdots1}}\\[6pt]
&=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: but this would not work if for example n=6 and r=1?

Comment: @JasonRig  Of course it does.  $$\frac{6!}{(6 - 1)!} = \frac{6!}{5!} = \frac{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot  1} = 6$$

Comment: Combinatorial reasoning and recursive definitions are too complicated, they say.  Let's use formulas and ellipses, they say.  Surely the students can deal with the extreme cases, they say.  And thus misunderstandings like this are produced, wasting entire hours of students' time as they plug in $r=1$ into their formulas and inexplicably end up with two $n$'s and some mysterious intermediate factors that don't correspond to anything.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, i meant in the n(n-1)(n-2)..(n-r+1) part because you will end up with 6(5)(4)...(5)

Comment: But you *don't* end up with those terms @JasonRig; for $r=1$ you just stop at $n$.  The $n-r+1$ 'th term is the smallest one in the descending product.  If it turns out to be $n$, it means there are no smaller factors and you just have $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply both by $(n-r)!$, you get $n!$.

Comment: Do you mean $(n-r)!$ instead of $r!$ ?

Comment: Oh, yeah. Oops. Fixed.